# Can I force bitbake to generate run.do_… files?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Calling `../temp/run.do_compile` in a second (tmux) window started by `bitbake -c devshell …` (or `menuconfig`) is very handy.

But when `devshell` gets started from a clean state, the file *run.do_compile* doesn't exist in *temp*. Calling `bitbake -c compile` before generates this file, but a compile might fail or take long.

Is it possible to tell bitbake to generate the file *run.do_…* in *temp* without calling it?